# java swing panel problems

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am having problems adding a panel to my main JFrame and hiding it right away, only making it visilble when a button it pressed. here is my code. Looking for any insight as to what the problem is. Also the label I try to add to the panel doesnt show up either.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package cis2430_a4;


import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
/**
 *
 * @author Tristan
 */
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 700;

    private JPanel addPanel;

public MainWindow()
{
    super("Day Planner");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    JLabel intro1 = new JLabel("Welcome to your Day Planner", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(intro1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel intro2 = new JLabel("Please choose an option from the menu bar above.", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(intro2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JMenu commands = new JMenu("Commands");

    JMenuItem addOption = new JMenuItem("Add");
    addOption.addActionListener(this);
    commands.add(addOption);

    JMenuItem searchOption = new JMenuItem("Search");
    searchOption.addActionListener(this);
    commands.add(searchOption);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(commands);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //add panel
    addPanel = new JPanel();
    addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addPanel.setSize(600,400);
    addPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    addPanel.add(new JLabel("add panel"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(addPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    addPanel.setVisible(false);


}

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
     /*String menuChoice = ae.getActionCommand();

     if (menuChoice.equals("Add")){
         addPanel.setVisible(true);
     }*/
     add(addPanel);
     //addPanel.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels are showing up because you have added a panel after adding the labels on the frame so basically the panels are overlapping the labels.
Also to show different panels you can use

```
 panel.setVisible(true); //For the panel you want to show and false for others
```

or you can use CardLayout which makes panels as cards and shows one of them at a time.

Comment: i only try to add one label on the panel that says "add panel". I want the other ones to be covered up by the panel. And i do use the panel.setVisible(false) and it does not hide the panel.

Comment: probably should have actually tried this before discounting it... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have no issue with your example.

You may want to...

1- Make sure you've launched your UI in the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            }

            MainWindow frame = new MainWindow();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

2- Try calling `repaint` after `addPanel.setVisible(true)`
3- Try calling `invalidate` after `addPanel.setVisible(true)` but before `repaint` if that doesn't work.

Much better solution is to use [Card Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for this kind of work

**UPDATED**

After spending some time reading through the code, what I think you seem to be concerned about is the fact that you're "intro" label isn't showing up...

This easily explained.  Only one component can exists at any given position within a `BorderLayout`, so when you add you `addPanel`, even though it's invisible, it will clobber the `intro2` label (effectively removing it from the container).

Below is an example using `CardLayout`

```
public class CardWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 700;
    private JPanel addPanel;

    private JPanel cardPane;
    private CardLayout cardLayout;
    private final JLabel intro2;

    public CardWindow() {
        super("Day Planner");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        cardPane = new JPanel((cardLayout = new CardLayout()));
        add(cardPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JLabel intro1 = new JLabel("Welcome to your Day Planner", JLabel.CENTER);
        add(intro1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        intro2 = new JLabel("Please choose an option from the menu bar above.", JLabel.CENTER);
        cardPane.add(intro2, "intro");

        JMenu commands = new JMenu("Commands");

        JMenuItem addOption = new JMenuItem("Add");
        addOption.addActionListener(this);
        commands.add(addOption);

        JMenuItem searchOption = new JMenuItem("Search");
        searchOption.addActionListener(this);
        commands.add(searchOption);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(commands);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JButton button = new JButton("Add");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //add panel
        addPanel = new JPanel();
        addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        addPanel.setSize(600, 400);
        addPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        addPanel.add(new JLabel("add panel"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addPanel.setVisible(false);
        cardPane.add(addPanel, "Add");

        cardLayout.show(cardPane, "intro");

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String menuChoice = ae.getActionCommand();
        System.out.println(menuChoice);
        if (menuChoice.equals("Add")) {
            cardLayout.show(cardPane, "Add");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                CardWindow frame = new CardWindow();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: well i need the panels to show up and hide when options from the commands menu bar are chosen. The button was there to see if i could hide with that instead.

Comment: Won't make any difference. The means by which you show the panels is irrelevant, the basic concept remains the same.  I'd still use a `CardLayout` for this work, because it will make you're life considerably easier in the long wrong

Comment: @TristanPearce I've updated the answer with an example I think will solve you basic problem

Answer (score 1):

Just edited the code a little but it seems to work -

[image]

```
public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public static final int WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 700;

    private JPanel addPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }
public MainWindow()
{
    super("Day Planner");
    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    JLabel intro1 = new JLabel("Welcome to your Day Planner", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(intro1, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JLabel intro2 = new JLabel("Please choose an option from the menu bar above.", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(intro2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JMenu commands = new JMenu("Commands");

    JMenuItem addOption = new JMenuItem("Add");
    addOption.addActionListener(this);
    commands.add(addOption);

    JMenuItem searchOption = new JMenuItem("Search");
    searchOption.addActionListener(this);
    commands.add(searchOption);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.add(commands);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JButton button = new JButton("Add");
    button.addActionListener(this);
    add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //add panel
    addPanel = new JPanel();
    addPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    addPanel.setSize(600,400);
    addPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    addPanel.add(new JLabel("add panel"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(addPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    addPanel.setVisible(false);


}

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
 {
     String menuChoice = ae.getActionCommand();

     if (menuChoice.equals("Add")){
         addPanel.setVisible(true);
     }
     add(addPanel);
     //addPanel.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: No edit but just uncommented the lines... The example code is working... Plus refer this question for CardLayout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338229/how-to-make-an-added-jpanel-visible-inside-a-parent-jpanel/11338493#11338493

Comment: so is there a problem with netbeans or something then?  No matter what I do it will not change my program. The action listener shouldn't effect the initial setup of the panel..

Comment: the panel colour isnt changing nor is the label appearing, and it isnt hidden when i start the program.

Comment: this is after i press the button